# Localizing UIViewController using Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4.6

I have pre-existing UIViewController with localization. I've added new UIViewController in the default English Local and I was expecting it will create for me same form in the other Storyboard local. But that is didn't happen.

So now, I only have this new UIViewController in English Storyboard only.

Is there away, either to copy this new UIViewController to the other Storyboard local, or instruct Xcode to create this UIViewController in the other local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced the same problem, so I just selected new UIViewController (whole VC scene) in "English" storyboard and copy-pasted it to another locale's storyboard. Then I made my "locale dependent" changes.

Comment: How did you copy the UIViewController, becouse when I go to "Edit", i see the "copy" item disabled.

Comment: just select it with a mouse or click on a status bar, you will see that your ViewController will be glowed with blue light. Then just CMD + C  ->  CMD + V

Answer (score 2):

In your Project properties, If you use the `Localizations` section, there you can add the localized language and related resources for the localized language. It will ask you to generate particular files/resource for localized language, resources can be your controllers, plist files,localizable files etc.

Comment: I think I did what you mentioned, and it copies the storyboard views to the other locals. But now when I added new UIViewController, it didn't copy it.

Comment: If you are adding new resources after localizing , you might need to add the resources again for that particular file.

Answer (score 1):

If you just have a new viewcontroller you can copy/paste, but if you have a lot of new changes look at [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cF1Rf02QvZQ) and read the description too, the guy created a python script that changes other storyboads according to the base storyboard you select, adding new items to the other localized storyboards.
I tried some time ago and worked.